# how to get the remaining time of the song which is played in AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I am new to iphone. I am working on audio player. I have to show the current time  and remaining time of the song in audioplayer. In video player it will gets as default but in audioplayer it is not getting so that i write a logic for getting current time of the song. The code below is for that

```
int minutes = (int)audioPlayer.currentTime / 60;
int seconds = (int)audioPlayer.currentTime % 60;
startDurationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d",minutes,seconds];
```

here audioPlayer is instance of AVAudioPlayer and startDurationLabel is the label for display the current time of the song.

But I am struggling to get this logic to work and show the remaining time of the song

If any body know this please help me...

Answer (score 2):

```
NSTimeInterval remaining = audioPlayer.duration - audioPlayer.currentTime;
```

Comment: As I don't have enough reputation here to comment anything but my own postings, I'll leave the comment here. While using a GCFloat as @Ayaz is suggesting will work, it is not semantically correct. The CGFloat is used by Core Graphics, and these are not graphically properties. Under the hood the NSTimeInterval is typedef'ed as a double, and CGFloat as a float. Therefore casting the subtracted return value, will lose precision (Although it shouldn't matter much when only displaying seconds anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
CGFloat remainingTime =   audioPlayer.duration - audioPlayer.currentTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
NSString *strTimeLeft = [self getTimeFromTimeInterval:CMTimeGetSeconds(_player.currentItem.duration) - CMTimeGetSeconds(_player.currentTime)];
```

Add this method in your class

```
- (NSString*)getTimeFromTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval
{
    NSInteger interval = (NSInteger)timeInterval;
    NSInteger seconds = interval%60;
    NSInteger minutes = (interval/ 60)%60;
    //NSInteger hr = (interval/3600)%60;

    NSString *strTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",minutes,seconds];
    return strTime;
}
```